# How can asynchronous operations in ViewModel init{} cause memory leaks?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've been reading an [official Google document](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/state-production#initializing-state-production) about UI state production which states the following:

> Warning: Avoid launching asynchronous operations in the init block or constructor of a ViewModel. Asynchronous operations shouldn't be a side effect of creating an object because the asynchronous code may read from or write to the object before it is fully initialized. This is also referred to as leaking the object and it can lead to subtle and hard to diagnose errors. This is particularly important when working with Compose State. When the ViewModel holds Compose State fields, don't launch a Coroutine in the init block of the ViewModel that updates the Compose State fields, otherwise an IllegalStateException may occur.

I'm struggling to understand how a memory leak could occur in this situation. Every MutableState has an initial value, so if another object reads the state, it would just read the default value and a memory leak shouldn't happen.

Am I missing something here? Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: They’re not talking about a *memory* leak. They’re talking about the risk of an asynchronous operation touching members of a class before it is fully constructed. However, if you are using `viewModelScope` for your async operation such that members of the view model are touched only on Dispatchers.Main, I would expect it to be safe because the view model itself is instantiated on the main thread, so there would be no opportunity for such a thing to occur.